# Bootstrap 3 - Responsive navbar, how to exclude some items from collapsing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Bootstrap so I'm having difficulties with responsive navbar. 
This is what I want to see:
Brand - search bar - messages/notifications - empty space - links on right side

Everything should collapse on small devices except Brand and messages/notifications.

This is what I've tried: http://www.bootply.com/HqordmjhNT

On previous link searchbar should come before messages/notifications, but what ever I tried to do, searchbar doesn't collapse.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Your link tell me i got the login or signup :(

Comment: @youngshot I edited my question, try now

Answer (score 0):

You can remove links from a responsive collapsing navbar by adding custom styles, here is my pen 
http://www.bootply.com/LdOCkcUulF#

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.navlink {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

            <a class="navlink" href="#">Messages <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="navlink" href="#">Notifications</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: This is closest to what I need. Is it possible to have this layout (for desktop): brand - search - messages/notifications - empty space - more links

Answer (score 0):

Sure just add the form after the brand

```
http://www.bootply.com/3R7nL9D87h

/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.navlink {
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
       <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

       <a class="navlink" href="#">Messages <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       <a class="navlink" href="#">Notifications</a>


    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


</div>
```

Comment: Did you see it in responsive mode, in this example search bar is not collapsed on small devices. This is the problem which I can't solve, I also tried before this example which you posted, but couldn't collapse search bar and keep messages/notifications uncollapsed.